# Checking if first character is Uppercase regex

Tags: c#, wpf, regex

I have created a regex that only allows the user to enter numbers and letters.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

I wanted to make sure that the first character is uppercase so I looked up how to do it and i changed my equation to this:

```
^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

I tested my equation on a few sites that test regex and it works properly but when I put it into my program it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: How are you calling it? What input data are you giving it?

Comment: Why doesn't it seem to work? What goes wrong?

Comment: Why not just UPPERCASE the first character programmitically?

Comment: well i have an if statment : if (Myregex.Match(myString).Success){return true}else {return false}

Comment: I want it to get rejected if its not uppercase

Comment: what goes wrong is that it returns false when i have an uppercased word with no symbols or spaces

Comment: Why not make your site easier to use instead of making your users jump through hoops?

Comment: well i do more inside that if

Comment: @BoltBait: its more of an equation editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Regex method that allows you to specify a [RegexOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) value, with `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` turned off.

Answer (score 5):

Change `^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+$` to `^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$`.  If it is `^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+$` then you are requiring a 2 character string, the first letter of which is capital.  The modified version allows 1 character strings as well. Does that help?

Comment: and H.B : that does help as i didnt think of that before. It still does not enter my if statment if my input starts with a capital. I'm not sure why im getting downvoted for making my user jump through hoops but the equation editor requires the user to enter a capital letter to start off with